# Sphere Geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I am writing a computer program about differential geometry, and i am stucked with geodesics on sphere.

I used a parametrization

$$
X = Rcos(v)sin(u)
$$
$$
Y = Rcos(u)
$$
$$
Z = Rsin(v)sin(u)
$$

so the metric is:
$$
g_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    R^2  &     0  \\
   0    &   R^2 sin^2(u)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

after realizing that standard geodesic equation is hard to solve for sphere i solved it by using Euler-Lagrange equation. The result was:

$$
u = cos^{-1}(Bcot(v)) + u_0
$$

where $B$ and $u_0$ are constants. With given endpoints, I solved for $B$ and $u_0$. In my program I wrote a script which shows curve on sphere surface using parametrization of (u,v), so i tried it that way:

$$
v = t
$$
$$
u = cos^{-1}(Bcot(t)) + u_0
$$

where $t$ is a parameter. And here I met 3 problems.

1. Equation doesn't work for $t=0$, because of the domain of $cot(t)$
2. Constants cannot be calculated when one of endpoints has v = $k\pi/2$ again because of the domain of the $cot(t)$
3. Weird behaviour near poles when i finally managed to run a program

Can I avoid this problem? Is it a better way to parametrize? or do i need to code sphere geodesics in other way?

Comment: Geodesics on a sphere are all great circles. If you want to see an analytic derivation from the differential equations, look at p. 72 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). My personal recommendation would be to take one great circle through the north pole and apply a rotation matrix to get the general case. :)

Comment: Thanks! I knew previously that great circles are geodesics on sphere, but I am not sure how to make a rotation correctly, because I am not sure about using standard 2D rotation matrix. For sure if i use it also changes metric so geodesic wouldn't be that easy to calculate. But maybe i think about it in wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an (oriented) orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2$ for the plane you want, and take $(\cos t)e_1+(\sin t)e_2$. If you like, this specifies the starting point $e_1$ on the unit sphere and the unit tangent vector $e_2$ at that point.

Comment: Thanks! After few days break I worked (almost) everything out using this method. I want only to ask is it worthy to show full solution here for people who will come here with similar problem? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know how to make this solution any more "full."

Comment: I mean to show how I worked everything out and show general solution for cartesian and spherical cordinates which i get for Sphere with any radius